# Youtube Videos playing simultaneously even when modal window is closed (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming

In my client website, when we play youtube videos in modal windows, they keep playing as we close the window.

Site: https://apoloi9.com.br. 
Each of the html list elements, where the videos and names are organized (as shown in the picture bellow), have unique id, but I couldn't find a way to make it work.

[Section specified in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2rGx.jpg)

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Be sure to **[Be on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. `Update your question` with just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: It sounds like the modal is being hidden instead of removed/emptied on close. Because you did not provide what model you are using, or any sample code, I don't think there's much we'll actually be able to help you with, however.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to empty or reload the src of the video embed. Therefore it would  be stopped. Assuming you use JQuery:

```
$("#yourModal").on("hide",function(){
    var video=$('.yourEmbed').attr("src");
    $('.yourEmbed').attr("src",video);
});
```

These actions can also be achieved using plain Javascript.